# Deploy Sample Data Content to app/code folder instead of vendor

Tags: magento2, sample-data, command-line, deployment, vendor

I can deploy sample data to vendor folder with with the command `bin/magento sampledata:deploy` in Magento 2 
however I want to edit this command to deploy sample data to app/code/magento folder instead of vendor.

Any ideas how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you tell me the reason, why do you want to change?

Comment: @krishnaati95Dev Because I'm using docker with only app code folder shared. I'm having performance issues with all files synchroned. So I want to edit sample files without login via ssh to my docker image everytime